# Solving Error " destination provider" when trying to save WMS as GeoTIFF

Tags: raster, wms, geotiff-tiff

I'm new and I use QGIS 3.10

I would like to save the WMS output as GeoTIFF to be able to load and clip the raster by a mask layer (polygon). When I try to save the WMS output as GeoTIFF (Export--> Save as) I get the message: "cannot write raster. Error: destination provider".

This is the window when I set the parameters:

[image]

In "name file" it makes me choose a folder in which to save the raster.
When I click "ok", I get the error: "cannot write raster. Error: destination provider"

Can you help me?

I tried to save in other folders but the error remains.

Comment: Does the WMS give GeoTIFF as an output

Comment: When I upload the WMS there were only PNG and JPEG output..Is it possibile save as a Geotiff anyway?

Comment: I'm trying to export ESRI hillshade https://qms.nextgis.com/geoservices/1495/ using this method i only get one small tile of the entire map instead of the zoomed area where i am

Answer (score 5):

I get the same error -

What triggers the error (in my case) is "Create VRT"

Once you deselect "Create VRT" you'll be able to save as "Raw Data" or "Visualized Image"

Answer (score 3):

You could try the following. Not sure if it works in your situation, but it did for me.

1. Select "rendered Image"
2. Deselect "Create VRT"
3. Make sure your map coordinate extents are set correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is kind of a bug.

For those who need VRT in daily workflow, alternative way is unfortunately to downgrade QGIS to 3.4.
Tested for me.