# Unable to view Raster Layers for calculation using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator

I am trying to put together a raster in QGIS 3.36 (and maybe convert to vector at some point) showing areas above 100 feet in NYC for calculating housing data. I have reviewed the SE responses/methodologies for doing so, but believe I am stuck on accessing the band information from the raster file when I try to use Raster Calculator. I think I have either messed something up in configuring the data connection to the raster source or in setting properties locally of the raster, but I am not sure.

Steps:

1. loaded raster file from https://elevation.its.ny.gov/arcgis/rest/services/NYC_TopoBathymetric2017_1_foot/ImageServer via Data Source Manager > ArcGIS REST Server
2. Layer appears to display correctly in the canvas, aligning with the base map coastline and showing values' extent
   [image: screenshot of elevation raster with opacity lowered over base map]
3. I don't see a histogram option in the layer properties, making me think that I've configured something wrong
   [image: layer properties menu]
4. When I open Raster Calculator, I don't see the option to select bands on the left. I've tried a few guesses in the expression window for the variables without luck: ("Topo">=100), ("Band 1">=100). Have tried both "create on-the-fly raster" and saving output layer to folder. First results in an empty layer, second results in "Could not create destination file" error.
   [image: Screenshot of raster calculator]
5. Error message:
   [image: Screenshot of error message]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to export to a local layer, as couldn't perform operations on the linked data.

From comment on [DTM hillshade function error: 'does not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a supported dataset name'](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/437199/dtm-hillshade-function-error-does-not-exist-in-the-file-system-and-is-not-rec) and troubleshooting in [Solving Error " destination provider" when trying to save WMS as GeoTIFF](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/351008/solving-error-destination-provider-when-trying-to-save-wms-as-geotiff)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).